# How do I fix small gap at top and on the left of iMac display?

Tags: display, imac

I have an iMac mid-2010 (11,3) that is showing a small gap at the top and left side of the screen in the built-in display. It is almost like the screen position is off, or the display is not being fully stretched. There used to be a way in System Preferences to change the screen position in older OSX versions, but that's since gone.

[image: Display Gap]

I did just replace RAM, could that cause this? And is there a way to fix it?

Comment: One way to see if the RAM is the culprit (I doubt it...) take it out and put the old RAM back in.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model with replaced RAM as well. You can try this. Open system preferences and click on display/Scaled. Now set the display to a couple of different resolution values and then return to your desired value. If offset is still apparent, try a different resolution.

Comment: I tried that and no dice. I'm wondering if the actual screen somehow got shifted inside of the computer.

Comment: It sounds that way but I have no idea how to check it.